# Pandas time conversion and elapsed time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time, jupyter

I have a pandas dataframe that has columns:

['A'] of departure time (listed as integer ex: 700 or 403 which is 7:00 and 4:03);

['B'] of elapsed time (listed as integer ex: 70 or 656 which is 70 mins and 656 mins);

['C'] of arrival time (listed as integer: 1810 and 355 which is 18:10 and 03:55).

I need to **find a way to develop a new column ['D'] with a boolean value that returns True if the arrival is on the following day and False if arrival is on the same day.**

I thought of accessing the -2 index of column A to convert hour to minute and then add the remainder minutes to normalize the values but not sure how to do that, or if there's a simpler way to find this. The idea behind this would be to get total minutes elapsed from moment the day started and if exceeds total minutes in a day, then I'd have my answer but unsure if this would work.

Comment: `101` -> 10:10 or 1:10? and is 24hr format used everywhere?

Comment: please provide us a sample of the dataset to assist you

Comment: @ anon01 24h is assumed to be everywhere, yes - there's no "am or "pm" info. 

@Cadone not sure how to add a sample of the dataset but I'll try. For what's worth, it's a .txt file with some 35 columns. These columns A, B and C were changed to int astype to help me calculate, but each column has the same amount of rows, about 1 million rows each. I *must* create a new column that iterates through each row and returns True for times that have exceeded onto the next day (A is for departure time, B is for time elapsed and C is for arrival time) but there is no date info, just time.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the method you outlined, you can accomplish the task by converting the integers in column `A` to a 24-hour datetime (starting from `1900-01-01`), adding the integer number of minutes from column `B` as a timedelta and then check to see if the result is still in day 1 of the month. As a sanity check, I made sure the last row should return `True`.

You can probably combine these steps without creating a new column, but I think the code is more readable this way.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[700,403,2359],
    'B':[70,656,2],
    'C':[810,1059,1]
})

# convert to string, add leading zeros, then convert column A to datetime
df['arrival'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'].astype(str).str.zfill(4), format='%H%M') + pd.to_timedelta(df['B'],'m')

# check if you are on day 1 of the month still
df['D'] = np.where(df.arrival.dt.day > 1, True, False)
```

Output:

```
      A    B     C             arrival      D
0   700   70   810 1900-01-01 08:10:00  False
1   403  656  1059 1900-01-01 14:59:00  False
2  2359    2     1 1900-01-02 00:01:00   True
```

Comment: Thank you Derek. I know I didn't mention on the question, but there is no "date" info. Is it necessary to add the datetime and go through all of this? Also, you created a dictionary with each column value there, but in the real data set, I have millions of rows, that doesn't seem to work with df['A]:df['A'] in between the braces {}.

Comment: I know there is no date info, but the datetime defaults to 1900-01-01, which is actually useful because then you can tell when you have reached the next day. Also the `df` DataFrame I created is purely an example. You can the code past that point on your DataFrame. I don't know if this is the most efficient method, as there might be a trick to make it faster, but let me know if it works.